# Can Google index a non-80/non-443 URL?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

Forgive me if this is a rather simple question but I have never encountered any search results before where they used a non-80 port on HTTP or non-443 port on HTTPS.

Screenshots or sample of search results with custom ports would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sites can be picked up on alternates ports. As an example, search for https://www.google.co.uk/#q=:8080

You should see a result for Outgoing Port Tester on `http://portquiz.net:8080` listed.

A bit further down you'll also see GLCF: Earth Science Data Interface on `http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/` too.

Comment: You can definitely do that, but I'd tend towards using subdomains / hostnames: many users don't understand port numbers and might be confused with them (eg how do they recommend the website to others?).

Comment: @JohnMueller That's something I thought about, the users will have to memorize the port.

Answer (score 1):

Other standard ports include 8000 and 8080 for HTTP.  But, since the port is physically specified in the HTTP URL, google can fetch from any port.