# Using different port for your website affects your SEO ranking?

Tags: seo

Let us say I have a https://example.com.. Then in my https://example.com/apps/ page I have a link going to https://example.com:8081/download/1/ where it will download a particular app.

Will having a page with different port affect my SEO ratings? When I say affect, I meant:

- Crawlers will detect this and reduce my SEO weight
- Just using https://example.com/download/1/ could have helped me gain more SEO weight

Comment: I would posit yes - Google does not often return results on non-default ports.

Comment: Alternate ports make the URL so ugly that they are seldom used. They're most often used by people trying to host at home on unreliable connections so when you do encounter them the sites tend to be poor quality. Even if Google doesn't use port number the ranking factor, it is certainly factors into usability and professionalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Google can crawl any port.  See [Can Google index a non-80/non-443 URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67060/can-google-index-a-non-80-non-443-url)

However, I think there's a clue to your question in John Mueller (Google) comments in the above question.  John doesn't say anything about it impacting SEO.  That doesn't mean it doesn't, but I think that if it did impact SEO, he probably would have said something.

The question remains, if Google can find your content, does the non standard port enter into their ranking algorithm?  Does the user needing to remember the port as alluded to in the above question, impact whether Google thinks the content is any less valuable, even though Google will provide the full link with the port number?

I would propose a test.  Create a page with a link to a page on a non default port.  Watch your weblogs on the secondary server for crawling from Google.  Additionally, create a site/property in Google Search Console for your non default port site.

Now, watch your weblogs and GSC for clues to whether Google crawls your secondary site, how often and what kind of data GSC can give you about queries and search position.

One last thought.  I'm guessing that if the page linking to the non default port link ever goes down, you're likely to lose all SEO ranking.  It's unlikely that Google does a port scan of servers with their bot to find web servers.  As a result, they presumably only look for 80,443, and maybe 8080 unless there's a link pointing to a non standard port.

Comment: I only have a link to a non-standard port. But I just used the default port instead. Just to make sure